# MBProgressHud touch event responding slowly when Downloading is done in asynchrous mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurl, mbprogresshud

I have the following code

```
-(void)singleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)sender
{
  NSLog(@"%@",@"tapped");

  [self setDownLoadLabel:[SAGlobal stringForValue:@"CANCELLINGDOWNLOAD"] withSubHeading:@""];
  SharedAppDelegatee.downLoadCancelFlag=YES;
  [self.downloadManager cancelAll];
  [self.downLoadHud hide:YES];
  [self downLoadButtonStatusSetter];
}

-(void) startFileDownLoadingWithHUD
{
  self.downLoadHud=[MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:[SharedAppDelegate window] animated:YES];
   //  self.downLoadHud=[MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];

  self.downLoadHud.mode = MBProgressHUDModeIndeterminate;
  UITapGestureRecognizer *HUDSingleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(singleTap:)];
  [self.downLoadHud addGestureRecognizer:HUDSingleTap];
  [self setDownLoadLabel:@"Initializing..." withSubHeading:@""];
  //self.downLoadHud.labelText = @"Initiali";
  //self.downLoadHud.detailsLabelText =@"";
  [self.downLoadHud setColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
  [self startDownLoadFilesSerially];
```

}

[image]

MBProgress tap gesture is responding slowly. It took some time to execute the "tapped" event. After touching the hud , it tooks some 10 seconds to execute the  NSLog(@"%@",@"tapped");
The Download is done using the following library.

https://github.com/robertmryan/download-manager

Is there any other way to capture the touch event in MBProgressHUD? Possible alternatives?

Comment: I think you probably need to check your code whether the operation is highly async.

Comment: Show the code where you call `[self startFileDownLoadingWithHUD]`